# Polynomials with some special sum divisible by all linear polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, divisibility

Let $\{F_i\}$ be given quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. If for every linear polynomial $l$, there exists linear polynomials $\{l_i\}$ (depend on $l$) such that

(i) $\sum l_i F_i$ is devisible by $l$.

(ii) Not every $l_i$ is a multiple of $l$.

Is it true that $\sum l_i F_i=0$ for some $\{l_i\}$?

---

I have no idea how to approach this. Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "is devided by"?

Comment: @user26857 I mean it is of the form $Ql$, where $Q$ is a quadratic polynomial.